# html table focus-highlight

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this table and script in my html, i Just want that if the user click the **" Select "** button it will change the color of what the user selected.

```
<table id="myTable" class="my_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Control #</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Education Level</th>
        <th>Section</th>
        <th>Course/Track</th>
        <th>Strand</th>
        <th>Payment Type</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Operation</th>
    </tr>
    {% for article in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.Student_Users }}</td>
        <td>{{article.Education_Levels}}</td>
        <td>{{article.Section}}</td>
        <td>{{article.Courses}}</td>
        <td>{{article.strands}}</td>
        <td>{{article.Payment_Type}}</td>
        <td>{{article.Date_Time}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'selectrecord' %}?StudentID={{ article.id }}"><button>Select</button></a><a href="#"></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    <tr>
        <td>No Data yet.</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[image]

```
<script>
.my_table tr:focus {
  background-color: red;
  outline: 0; /*remove outline*/
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you want multiple selection or just one selected row at a time??

Comment: Just one selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a class on TR on click of select button and change the CSS accordingly

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.select').click(function(){
    $('tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
  });
});
```

```css
#myTable th, #myTable td {border-bottom: 1px solid; white-space: pre-wrap;}
#myTable tr.selected td {background: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="my_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Control #</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Education Level</th>
        <th>Section</th>

    </tr>
    {% for article in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.Student_Users }}</td>
        <td>{{article.Education_Levels}}</td>
        <td><a href="#javascript:void(0)"><button class="select">Select</button></a><a href="#"></a></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.Student_Users }}</td>
        <td>{{article.Education_Levels}}</td>
        <td><a href="#javascript:void(0)"><button class="select">Select</button></a><a href="#"></a></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
        <td>{{ article.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ article.Student_Users }}</td>
        <td>{{article.Education_Levels}}</td>
        <td><a href="#javascript:void(0)"><button class="select">Select</button></a><a href="#"></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by #javascript:void(0)?

Comment: @justin you used  button inside an anchor, I don;t know why you did that, I don't want to chnage your HTML, and need to avoid the redirect as well, so added this for demo purpose only, just tell me what you want to do with this anchor?

Comment: what is the purpose of #javascript:void(0)?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-javascriptvoid0-mean/